# Python is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My python is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, when I uninstall the old version (`3.9`) to the new version (`3.10`), i have tried to update my path in the environment variable, but it still goes to the previous python (3.9)

here's my path :

[Update Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coptp.png)

[error occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRPNk.png)

```
PS D:\CodingFile> & C:/Users/amirc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/python.exe "d:/CodingFile/Python/Latihan Kuliah/Struktur-Data/amir.py"
& : The term 'C:/Users/amirc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/python.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & C:/Users/amirc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/pytho ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/amirc/...ipts/python.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

the error occurs based on the information it is still on the old version path,can anyone help..

Comment: Welcome to SO.  How exactly are you running the new python version?   Is your ```& C:/Users/amirc/.../Scripts/python.exe..```  what you type in or is this some script?

Comment: i run it in visual studio code, i have tried in cmd there is no problem, what i run. just prints something and it doesn't run..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in vscode you might have to tell it to change its interpreter.
[See this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Answer (score 0):

mr freddy's answer is correct, but still can't run when I try manual, by opening visual studio code and running the program, more precisely I changed, python select interpreter, (CTRL + P, python: select interpreter) in visual studio code
, and set global env, thanks all

[Python : interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2mOH.png)